# Append target within target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
install-component-a:
    cp ...
    db reload

install-component-b:
    cp ...
    db reload

install-component-b:
    cp ...
    db reload
```

My Makefile does not only build but also installs the software to a system.

The snippet expounds the software have 3 components. Sometimes I update component a while the other times I may update component b and c.

The three targets all require the database to refresh.

In case I update all three components, and I run `make install`, I only need the database to refresh ONCE not three times.

Is there a way to schedule additional targets to run within a target?

I like something like this:

```
install-component-a:
    cp ...
    a-make-command-to-add-new-target reload-database

install-component-b:
    cp ...
    a-make-command-to-add-new-target reload-database

install-component-b:
    cp ...
    a-make-command-to-add-new-target reload-database

reload-database:
    db reload
```

Does such `a-make-command-to-add-new-target` exist?

Adding `reload-database` to the `all` target or the `install` target may not be ideal because if none of component a, b, and c changes, the db doesn't have to reload.

Answer (score 1):

Make recipes have the automatic variable `$?` which expands to the prerequisites newer than target.

```
install-component-a:
    cp ...

install-component-b:
    cp ...

install-component-c:
    cp ...

reload-database: install-component-a install-component-b install-component-c
    add new target $?
    db reload
```

Your example suggests the targets are not files. This may be an issue as all prerequisites are considered newer than a non-existing file. In case they are not consider having the components touch a file and use that file timestamp to determine necessity for rebuild.

Comment: I may not articulate clear enough. Is there a make command allowing me to dynamically add new target?

Comment: In your code, my contributors have to remember when to call `make reload-database` when they change component A, B or C. I want them to call `make install` and the make tool figures out if `reload-database` should be called or not, and only calls once.

Comment: @Gqqnbig Do they though? With this rule they'd never actually do `make component`, only `make reload-database` (or `make install` depending what it's supposed to do). Make dependencies makes sure only changed parts are rebuilt. You might also consider to print a message ("remember to also run command xxx") on MAKECMDGOALS being something special, such as a pattern matching components.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add new targets to be built from within the makefile.  What you appear to want is a way to define commands that will always be run once after all other rules have run.  There isn't something like that available.

The only way I know of to make this work is to recursively invoke make.  It would look something like this:

```
install-component-a install-component-b install-component-c: recurse ;

recurse:
        $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS:%=r-%)
        db reload

r-install-component-a:
    cp ...

r-install-component-b:
    cp ...

r-install-component-b:
    cp ...
```

Comment: This will run `db reload` even when none of the components were rebuilt. Argh, the woes of recursive make :-( Good solution nonetheless

Comment: Of course, we cannot know for sure because the question doesn't make it clear, but from what we can see it looks to me like these `install-component-X` rules are essentially phony rules: that is if you invoke `make install-component-a` it will always run that recipe: there's no way for make to detect if it's up to date or not.  Again I could be wrong since we weren't shown the actual recipes.  Just a hunch on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Use make's `eval` function, e.g. see [Metaprogramming Make VI — The eval Function](http://make.mad-scientist.net/the-eval-function/)

Comment: You don't show the solution you have in mind, but note that it's not possible to add extra prerequisites from within a recipe, even using `eval`.  Try it ...

Comment: Thanks for clarification!